# Blazor WASM styling missing when hosted in docker using nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

I have a strange issue, where my styling is broken when I try to host my blazor WASM project using Nginx. I tried to follow a couple of different guides and they were similar and had same issue for me.

I have the code here: https://github.com/TopSwagCode/Dotnet.IdentityServer/tree/master/src/BlazorClient

When I debug locally or publish locally and serve from dotnet serve I get the following:

[image]

But when I publish and try to run it within docker using Nginx I get this:

[image]

My buttons are still there, but I can't see them since they are white.

My dockerfile is pretty simple:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output
FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/web
COPY --from=build-env /app/output/wwwroot .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

My nginx config

```
events { }
http {
    include mime.types;
    types {
        application/wasm wasm;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        # Here, we set the location for Nginx to serve the files
        # by looking for index.html
        location / {
            root /var/www/web;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find any "not found" or similar in network tab.

Edit:

When comparing both running side by side, I was not able to find CSS for linear-gradient, which is the purple side of the menu. Digging a bit deeper, it seems all CSS in MainLayout.razor.css was not being found.

https://github.com/TopSwagCode/Dotnet.IdentityServer/blob/master/src/BlazorClient/Shared/MainLayout.razor.css

When running locally:

[image]

When running using Docker+Nginx

[image]

So seems to me, the CSS is missing somehow???

Edit 2:

The build hash for CSS seems to not match after deploy.
So I found the CSS file linked on my Page to be like the following:

[image]

But my HTML doesn't match that. It looks like this:

[image]

Don't know how that can break during build and deploy for Docker+Nginx??? Is there something I am doing wrong in my dockerfile???

Comment: any errors in browser console? f12

Comment: None. Adding a small edit. Found something strange with linear-gradient not showing at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After way to long time spending debugging this issue, I finally got it working.
I found this project: https://github.com/waelkdouh/DockerizedClientSideBlazor/ and started comparing. Only thing different I could see, what he had a .dockerignore
I made a copy of it and it all started working. Have no idea what was the issue. Can't see how any of the files listed could break the CSS.....

Comment: Also clearing the `bin` and `obj` files from my local project, not sure which one really helped

Comment: I also spent too long looking into this.  Clearing the bin/obj folders didn't work for me, adding a dockerignore file didn't seem to take either.    Ended up doing a git clean while walking through my commits and that itself fixed it.  So it's something sort of cached file(s) from my host getting copied over into into the image for building.  Odd that VS gets around it but dotnet build in a container doesn't.

Comment: @Jim your suggestion worked for me, thanx

Answer (score 8):

I've run into this issue before as well.
Delete your bin a obj folders.
There seems to be some caching issues where the generated scope in scoped css wont match between debug and release.

Comment: This might be a solution! I got into the same error. The sidebar went missing. After I deleted `bin` and `obj` folders of the Blazor WASM project, I built the image again and ran perfectly, having the sidebar again.

Comment: weirdly it works when I check the files before publish with http-server but when I upload to a remote server I still have that issue

Comment: Update: this was Cloudflare cache

Answer (score 0):

**Exclude bin and obj folder via dockerignore**
Excluding the *bin* and *obj* folders via the *.dockerignore*, should fix this issue.

Add in .dockerignore file:

```
# Exclude build artifacts
**/bin/
**/obj/
```

**NOTE:** Still after adding this, the problem might occur. You can then try the following:

**Clear docker build cache**
Docker might have cached some layers to. You can add *--no-cache* to the docker build to make sure no cached layers are used

```
docker build --no-cache {other docker build flags here}
```

**Think about browser cache** Also make sure that your browser cache is cleared (or open in browser incognito mode to make sure "old" css is not cached in the browser). This can easily be forgotten and then it still looks like the css is not loaded correctly.

**Clear local project info** If all of that did not work, you can also try to do a *clean* on your project/solution and delete the *obj and bin* folders of your WASM project.