# Blazor WASM CSS Not loading on published container

Tags: c#, docker, nginx, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm having issues with a Blazor WebAssembly project that don't render the css styles of the components with css isolation after I published to a docker container. In the development scenario works fine, but when I build it to a docker container it doesn't apply styles to my components.
My docker file looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build

COPY /src/SDK/XTOS.PlayerUI.SDK.csproj /src/SDK/XTOS.PlayerUI.SDK.csproj
RUN dotnet restore /src/SDK/XTOS.PlayerUI.SDK.csproj
COPY /src/SDK/ /src/SDK

COPY /src/WebClient/XTOS.PlayerUI.WebClient.csproj /src/WebClient/XTOS.PlayerUI.WebClient.csproj
RUN dotnet restore /src/WebClient/XTOS.PlayerUI.WebClient.csproj
COPY /src/WebClient/ /src/WebClient/

WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet build WebClient/XTOS.PlayerUI.WebClient.csproj -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish /src/WebClient/XTOS.PlayerUI.WebClient.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM nginx:alpine AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=publish /app/publish/wwwroot .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

It is building with nginx for the serving of the files. The nginx conf file looks like this:

```
events { }
http {
    include mime.types;

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=120r/s;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

            limit_req zone=one burst=60;
        }
    }
}
```

No errors occurs when loading the media, even the css files are received in the browser and are referenced in the  of the index.html, but is like the components are not using them.

Comment: Make sure the publish step doesn't fail, this generates specific CSS that is needed when in release mode.

Comment: It doesn't fail, it generates the css, and actually it's loading in the browser sources. The thing apparently is that the ids of the components and the css generated doesn't match. I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: I hit this issue earlier and after seeing https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772979/739409 I made sure the bin and obj folders were not getting passed through to the docker build (by adding **/bin and **/obj to my .dockerignore file) and it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by excluding the /bin and /obj folders from copying to the docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing to a Linux-Container leads to this problem.

Filename is 'Styles.css' but within _Layout.cshtml there is a reference to 'css/styles.css' (lowercase).

Because Linux is case sensitive on filenames, 'styles.css' is not found.

There are two options to resolve the problem.

1. Rename your 'Styles.css' file into 'styles.css' (you may loose source control history)
2. Within _Layout.cshtml replace
   'href="css/styles.css"'
   with
   'href="css/Styles.css"'