# asp.net blazor css files not working with docker

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, blazor

I have problem after deploy blazor app to docker desktop the css files are not working
Although when I debug throw chrome I get 200 status code for all the content in the website including css files..but they are not applied to the site

here live demo for both sites one working with IIS (which working fine) and the other with docker(where I Have the problem)

docker version
http://adel.giize.com

IIS version
http://adel.giize.com:8080

here is the dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build

WORKDIR /src

COPY JanGym.csproj .

RUN dotnet restore "JanGym.csproj"

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish "JanGym.csproj" -c Release -o /publish


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 as final 

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /publish .


ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","JanGym.dll"]
```

**Update 1**

I notice that the third party components like MudBlazor they components working fine in my app

**Update 2**

I tried this Dockerfile and got the same result

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src

COPY ["JanGym.csproj","."]

RUN dotnet restore "JanGym.csproj"

COPY . .

RUN dotnet build "JanGym.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish

RUN dotnet publish "JanGym.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","JanGym.dll"]
```

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66769510) contains a lot of solutions. One of them should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `Program.cs` - try to add one line bellow CreateBuilder

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(builder.Environment, builder.Configuration); //Add this
```

or in .dockeringore exlude files

```
**/bin
**/obj
```

Comment: Thanks, the `StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets` method worked for me. Updating the .dockerignore did not.